# highlight selected week of asp.net calendar

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I need to highlight the week on base of selected date in asp.net calendar. As we can specify style for the selected date, do asp.net calendar have option to specify style for the entire week of the selected date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use calendar_dayrender event

```
public void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        DataRow[] rows = Tables.Select(
              String.Format(
                 "Date='{0}' and Month='{1}' and Year='{2}'",
                 e.Day.Date.Day,
                 e.Day.Date.Month,
                 e.Day.Date.Year
              )
           );

        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image;
                image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                 if (somecondition)
                {

                    e.Cell.CssClass = "cssclass";

                }



    }
```